# How to make table height automatically the most compact

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularx

I would like to automatically adjust the height of my tabularx rows such that it occupies the minimum of space.

Consider the following code:

```
\small
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
\hline
\textbf{AA} & \textbf{[BB]-[CC]} & \textbf{DD \& general EE}\\
\hline 
aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  & aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  & aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  \\
\hline
aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  & aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  & aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  \\
\hline
aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  & aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  & aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  \\
\hline
aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  & aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  & aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\normalsize
```

If you display it, you will find something like this:

[image]

What I would like is the third column to be wider such that the row take less height. But I would like that latex does it automatically for me (I don't want to think about which width should the third column be such that the full row takes less height). How can I do this?

In this example each row contain the same elements but in general the rows could have a different content.

Comment: use tabulary not tabularx

Answer (score 5):

By use of the `tabulary` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \small
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|L|L|L|}
    \hline
\textbf{AA} & \textbf{[BB]-[CC]} & \textbf{DD \& general EE}\\
    \hline
aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  & aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  & aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  \\
    \hline
aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  & aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  & aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  \\
    \hline
aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  & aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  & aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  \\
    \hline
aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  & aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  & aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  \\
    \hline
\end{tabulary}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like at this to have column headers in one line, xopu should define minimal width of columns. For this in your case add `\tymin=5em` before `\begin{tabulary}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \small
    \tymin=5em
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|L|L|L|}
% table body is the same as before
\end{tabulary}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Intuitively, your objective may be achieved by setting the column widths such that the depths of the cells are (roughly) equal. If you wish to keep using a `tabularx` environment, I suggest you set the usable width of the third column to ten [10!] times the usable width of the first two columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|L{0.25}|L{0.25}|L{2.50}|} % 0.25+0.25+2.5=3
\hline
\textbf{AA} & \textbf{[BB]-[CC]} & \textbf{DD \& general EE}\\
\hline 
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa & aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa & aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  \\
\hline
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa & aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa & aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  \\
\hline
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa & aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa & aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  \\
\hline
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa & aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa & aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\hsize=<factor>\hsize` trick, which is more customizable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\hsize=\fpeval{#1}\hsize}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\small

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|Y{1/2}|Y{1/2}|Y{2}|}
\hline
\textbf{AA} & \textbf{[BB]-[CC]} & \textbf{DD \& general EE}\\
\hline 
aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  &  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  &
  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa
  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa
  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa
  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa
  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa
  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa
  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa
  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa
  aa aa  \\
\hline
aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  &  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  &
  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa
  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa
  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa
  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa
  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa
  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa
  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa
  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa  aa aa
  aa aa  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The arguments to `Y` should sum to the number of desired `X` columns, in this case 3.

[image]

These arguments can be fractions, which eases the computations, but you might also input `Y{0.5}` for this case.

With

```
|Y{1/2}|Y{1}|Y{3/2}|
```

you get

[image]

Note `\small` inside `center`. There's very rarely (if ever) the need to issue `\normalsize` in a LaTeX document.